# Need to apply filter on using OR condition

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have Dataset in PowerBI as below.
In PowerBI Desktop I want to filter records of below table based on condition described below.

```
ProjectName  ReleaseDate  UserReleaseDate
PROJ-1       12/09/2019   null
PROJ-2       null         02/02/2019
PROJ-3       07/07/2018   null
```

Date are in DD/MM/YYYY format.

I want to filter those records where

```
 (ReleaseDate OR UserReleaseDate is IsInNextNYears(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much just do exactly what you described.

```
Table.SelectRows(YourTable, each (Date.IsInNextNYears([ReleaseDate], 1) or Date.IsInNextNYears([UserReleaseDate], 1)))
```

If you use any filter operation on a column in Power Query it will automatically create a Table.SelectRows step that you can edit to do what you want instead.

Comment: I have tried same, but it is not considering OR condition.
I think first it filters records using `Date.IsInNextNYears([ReleaseDate], 1)` then go for OR condition.

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of what you want the filter to accomplish? In your sample data this filters out PROJ-3 while keeping PROJ-1 and PROJ-2, which is correct for how an OR conditional is supposed to work. I would also note that function is only looking at the year value of the date, it does not care about the months or days.

Comment: `Table.SelectRows(YourTable, each (Date.IsInNextNYears([ReleaseDate], 1) or Date.IsInNextNYears([UserReleaseDate], 1)))`

Gives me only PROJ-1.

I want a result to have PROJ-1, PROJ-2.

Comment: Are you sure both of your columns have their data type set as dates? PROJ-1, PROJ-2 is the result I get. I can't say anything for sure without seeing a screenshot or the M code.